# Method for transforming one curve around another?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, transformation, quadratics

I'm working with a complex problem involving waveforms. Essentially I want to bend a given waveform around a circle.

At it's most basic, I want to take one curve on a linear graph and map it onto a circular graph.

I'm wondering if anyone knows what the mathematical formula is for the transformation around the circle if I know what the original curve is?

[To help explain the problem I've drawn this diagram. My starting point is the top graph and my desired end point is the bottom one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk45x.png)

I might be thinking about the problem the wrong way, so any guidance would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Here is a related question (I'm not sure if it will answer yours, but it may be of interest!) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238534/is-imposing-one-function-onto-another-ever-used-in-mathematics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example like

$ y= A \sin ^{2} 2 \pi \,x/ \lambda + b  $

And you want to wind it around a circle radius $r_1$

Angle at circle center  $ \theta  =  x/r_1 $ then

$ r = r_1+ A \sin ^{2} 2 \pi r_1 \theta / \lambda + b $

So you basically substitute $ x = \theta r_1$ and add to the radius to be bent.

Next new $(X,Y):$

$ X = r \cos \theta, Y = r \sin \theta ..$